# GCC inserts a PXOR when casting int to float

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86-64, sse

I noticed when I try to cast an `int` to `float` then `GCC` (with -O3) inserts a `PXOR` instruction.

```c
float
f(int n) {
    return n;
}
```

this would generate:

```
f:
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0             ; this line. 
        cvtsi2ss        xmm0, edi
        ret
```

## Question

- I can't understand why is it needed here. [This](https://uops.info/table.html) link says that `CVTSI2SS` is used for:

> Converting Doubleword Integer to Scalar Single-Precision Floating-Point Value.

Based on this document I don't understand why we need to insert a `PXOR` there.

#### Notes

- I couldn't find anything while searching on internet (I'm really having hard time for searching answers in `ASM` topic c: ).
- Previously I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66980246/why-does-gcc-include-an-empty-xor) why GCC inserts an "empty" `XOR`. And the explanation there is that I had a `UB` there and `GCC` saved me from me. But here casting an `int` to `float` isn't `UB` (If I'm not wrong).
- I thought that maybe explicitly saying that I want a float cast would help but no.

```c
float
g(int n) {
    return (float)n;
}
```

returns same asm:

```
g:
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        cvtsi2ss        xmm0, edi
        ret
```

- If I'm not wrong `int` is not defined to be exactly 32bits unlike `float`. So I thought maybe that's the reason. But following code didn't gave me the output I was looking for:

```c
float
h(int32_t n) {
    return (float)n;
}
```

this outputs:

```c
h:
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        cvtsi2ss        xmm0, edi
        ret
```

- Also interesting that `CLANG` doesn't have `PXOR` there.
- Finally the [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/849h4xGnq) link.

Comment: `cvtsi2ss` and similar were badly / shortsightedly designed by Intel to merge into the destination XMM register instead of zero-extending.  GCC is cautious and spends extra instructions to break dependencies just in case XMM0 was at the end of a long dep chain independent from EDI.  As usual, clang is reckless (although I think it might pxor inside a loop within a single function.)

Comment: Seems relevant: [**Usage of instruction pxor before SSE instruction cvtsi2ss**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42286779/usage-of-instruction-pxor-before-sse-instruction-cvtsi2ss)

Comment: @AndrewHenle what keywords did you use to find this question? c:

Comment: " I had a UB there and GCC saved me from me" is nonsense as if the behaviour is undefined then the compiler does NOT have to save you , that's the whole reason UB exists

Comment: @PeterCordes can I ask why `CLANG`  doesn't do it? if there's a bug there. Can I somehow visually see that? What should I write instead of this (just trying to understand the concept here c: )?

Comment: See my final edit to my previous comment: as usual, clang is just being reckless and hoping XMM0 wasn't last written by a cache-miss load or a dep chain involving one.

Comment: It seems the correctness of this would depend on the ABI, whether the caller is only supposed to read half of the register, or whether it may use all 64 bits

Comment: Possible duplicate [x86 - instruction interleaving to avoid cpu stall](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37906394) - I went into detail in multiple paragraphs about the bad design of `cvtsi2sd` that GCC is working around with PXOR, but it's not the main focus of the question.

Comment: @M.M: high garbage is allowed in registers outside the part that holds the real return value, in all mainstream x86 calling conventions. (I'm 100% sure about x86-64 System V; I even asked one of the ABI maintainers for clarification on that point once.)  That goes for XMM regs and also for integer regs.  e.g. `char foo(int x){return x;}` can do `mov eax, edi` instead of `movzx` if it wants.  Or tailcall a function returning `int`.  Also for xmm function args: apparently some FP libraries have had to be bugfixed when they caused spurious FP exceptions in high elements from scalar args.

Comment: @PeterCordes OK; neither of the two suggested duplicates so far mention that (I guess they seem to assume the asker already is aware, although in this question OP wasn't)

Comment: @M.M: Yeah, fair point, the fact that clang omits `pxor` in this case could have been (but isn't) due to undocumented calling-convention extensions / modifications, unlike for incoming narrow-integer args where clang depends on an undocumented extension that it and GCC both follow on the calling side ([Is garbage allowed in high bits of parameter and return value registers in x86-64 SysV ABI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40475902))

Comment: Ah, there we go, I knew I'd written about this before, and fortunately not just as a pet-peeve footnote in other answers.  [Why does adding an xorps instruction make this function using cvtsi2ss and addss ~5x faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60688348) is 100% about exactly the reason that GCC is using PXOR and clang isn't, in a case where it matters.  That answer collects up other related links, including the GCC missed-optimization bugs I've filed about better ways to work around it (with AVX).  Also fun fact: some compilers (MSVC IIRC) use `movd xmm0, edi` / `cvtdq2ps` to save uops.

Comment: @Hrant I used https://www.google.com/search?q=pxor++++xmm0%2C+xmm0